# Windows 11 + nVidia + AMD Video card, AMD card disappears and shows up as removeable?

Tags: graphics-card, windows-11, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver, amd-graphics-card

I have a Windows 11 system where I have an nVidia RTX 4070 Ti and an AMD RX 6600, I wanted to have this configuration because I want to test/develop 3D applications ( with vulkan ) without swapping cards all the time. Assumed it will work without major problems but it does strange things, one is in the title of the question. The AMD card is connected with a PCI-E riser of about 60cm of cable length, both cards bought brand new, separately they work as expected no issues at all, I've even tested both cards separately in a different system, they both worked fine. When both cards are 100% percent load the system is stable. Drivers for both cards are the latest drivers available at the time of asking this question.

One of the major issues I have is that if the RTX is the one that is driving both of my displays so the AMD card has no active display that it drives, it just disappears seemingly randomly, but closely related to starting anything 3D that places workload on it, then it might completely disconnect from the system, just like an USB device would I even hear the sound of "device disconnected", or It just does this on it's own after a few seconds of system uptime ( don't need to login for this to happen ), restarting the system just brings back the card and it disappears again after some time. After the "device disconnected" sound I can check the device manger and the AMD card is not even there, not able to get it back ( unless the system is rebooted ) and the outputs of the AMD card are all off.

What seems to fix the issue is that the AMD card drives one display and the nVidia card drives the other then both work in tandem and the disappearing is not a problem anymore.

If I open up the device manager and check both cards the AMD one has a CM_DEVCAP_REMOVEABLE which I don't understand how is even possible to have on a videocard.

[image: Device capabilities]

If I get the menu where you can see removable devices, the AMD card shows up as a 'VGA compliant device' and if I click on it does exactly what you would expect, it just disconnects the AMD card completely and it is the same thing as the issue mentioned above but this time it's done by me and not randomly by something.

[image: Shows up as an USB device]

If the setup works it works flawlessly both cards can output with proper FPS and there are no stuttering of glitches I can even open 2 applications that run on each card and it works fine, even if only one of the cards drive all the displays, albeit it has a penalty because windows has to copy one card's framebuffer to the one that drives the display but this is something I expected from a setup like this.

What could cause the AMD card just randomly disconnecting unless it's driving one of the displays? Could this be something caused by the riser?

Note: I cannot physically put both cards directly into the motherboard the RTX is too large and the motherboard's layout doesn't allow me to fit both cards at the same time, hence the requirement for a riser.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to update the motherboard BIOS.

I have an ASUS Z690-P motherboard, before the update it said that it has a BIOS dated 2021 ( don't remember the month ), updated to the latest built: 2023/07/07 and it fixed all the problems mentioned in the question.